# Filter в vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Не получается доделать фильтр. Подскажите в чем ошибка:

https://codepen.io/kvazarmw/pen/GEEqZr

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#blocks",
  data: {
    input: '',
    array: [{
        team: 'Детский лагерь',
        obl: 'Днепропетровская',
        city: 'Днепр',
        category: 'Лагерь'
      },
      {
        team: 'Детский лагерь',
        obl: 'Одесская',
        city: 'Одесса',
        category: 'Лагерь'
      },
      {
        team: 'Экскурсия по Львову',
        obl: 'Львовская',
        city: 'Львов',
        category: 'Экскурсия'
      },
      {
        team: 'Экскурсия по Ивано-франковску',
        obl: 'Инаво-франковская',
        city: 'Ивано-франковск',
        category: 'Экскурсия'
      },
      {
        team: 'Экскурсия по Ивано-франковску',
        obl: 'Инаво-франковская',
        city: 'Ивано-франковск',
        category: 'Экскурсия'
      }

    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filterArray: function() {
      var arrays = this.array,
        searchString = this.input;

      if (!searchString) {
        return arrays;
      }

      //searchString = searchString.trim();

      arrays = arrays.filter(function(item) {
        if (item.obl.indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
          return item;
        }
      })
      // Возвращает массив с отфильтрованными данными.
      return arrays;

    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}

.block {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.5/vue.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" v-model="input">

<div id="blocks">
  <div class="block" v-for="array in filterArray">
    <p>{{ array.team }}</p>
    <p>Область: {{ array.obl }}</p>
    <p>Город: {{ array.city }}</p>
    <p>Категория: {{ array.category }}</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

У вас `input` вне контейнера `#blocks`, поэтому vue не видит его, соответственно никакой реакции нет. Сделайте вот так:

```
...
<div id="blocks">
<input type="text" v-model="input">
...
```